# QMimeDatabase Error OpenCV Premature end of Document

Tags: python, qt, opencv, conda

Kindly need help with a strange errors related to **OpenCV** or **QT** in Python.

Here's the error:

```bash
QMimeDatabase: Error loading internal MIME data
An error has been encountered at line 1 of <internal MIME data>: Premature end of document.:
```

and this is my simple opencv code for stream a video:

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc('Y','1','6',' '))
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0)
cv2.namedWindow("frame", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.normalize(frame, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

I just ran a simple cv2 code to open a video stream from my webcam. Every time I do the video stream from OpenCV, this error shows. However, the program is successfully running normally, and the webcam window is opened, but this error message looks disturbing on my screen. lol

Did anyone get an idea how to get rid of this? Thank you in advance

Extra detail:

```
OS: Windows 10 64bit
Python: 3.7.15 runs using conda
OpenCV: 4.6.10 installed from conda-forge
Numpy: 1.21.5
qt-main: 5.15.2 (installed when installing opencv)
```

Answer (score 2):

Install opencv-contrib-python will solve the issue.

pip install opencv-contrib-python

Other details:
Windows 10/x64
Python: 3.10.9
Conda: 23.1.0
Opencv: 4.7.0
numpy: 1.23.5
qt-main: 5.15.2
pyqt: 5.15.7
pyqt5-sip: 12.11.0
qt-webengine: 5.15.9
qtwebkit: 5.212

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a different configuration (see below):

conda version : 22.9.0
conda-build version : 3.22.0
Python : 3.7.16
Opencv : 4.6

My issue arised on line calling :
`cv.waitKey(0)`

I figured it out by installing in the cmd:
`pip install opencv-contrib-python`